# Text automatically replaced by text

Tags: macos, text

When I type anywhere on my mac "test" it will be replaced with `echo "test". $ swag. "yolo"`.
I have an example uploaded to YouTube: https://youtu.be/H057jnDtsvc

I know that I used it somewhere one time in a part of code but I had deleted it.

I also checked my System Preferences → Keyboard → Text

Comment: Can you edit the question to make it clearer?

Comment: Anywhere? In a text editor or word processor? In a web-browser location field? _Anywhere?_

Comment: Sorry my English is not perfect.
With everywhere, I mean everywhere where I can type. In an editor, browser, Notes, Word, etc.

Comment: I had something similar, check this out:

http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/197408/os-x-unknown-ghost-text-expansion-automatically

Comment: Thanks @TrentMcClenahan, I use Dash and there was this snippet what appears when I used test.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just in a single app (TextEdit, Mail, Stickies, and so on) you may try to look for a substitution settings:

e.g. `Edit > Substitutions > Text Replacement`

Comment: Avoid asking questions in an answer. You have sufficient reputation to be able to ask these questions properly as a comment on the question.